# How to make different alignment in table header of longtable

Tags: horizontal-alignment, longtable

I want to make the last column of my `longtable` with different alignment. I want the header (center frequency column) to be aligned left, and the data in that column is aligned right. What should I modify from my code?

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, onecolumn, oneside, final]{report}
\makeatother

\usepackage{array}
\setlength\extrarowheight{4pt}

\usepackage{tabto}
\newenvironment{tabs}[1]
{\TabPositions{#1}}

\usepackage{longtable}  
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{musicography}

\begin{document}

\begin{small}
    \renewcommand\thetable{A}
    \begin{longtable}{ |C{3cm}|p{3cm}|r|p{3cm}| }
        
        \caption{Nomor not MIDI, nama not, dan \textit{center frequency}}\\
        \hline
        \textbf{Nomor Not MIDI} & \textbf{Nama Not} & \textbf{\raggedleft\textit{Center frequency}} \\
        \endfirsthead
        
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{\tablename~\thetable} Nomor not MIDI, nama not, dan \textit{center frequency} (Lanjutan)}\\
        \hline
        \textbf{Nomor Not MIDI} & \textbf{Nama Not} & \textbf{\raggedleft\textit{Center frequency}}
        \endhead
        
        \hline
        127 & G9                        & 12,543.85 \\
        
        \hline
        126 & F$\sharp$9 / G$\flat$9    & 11,839.82 \\
        
        \hline
        125 & F9                        & 11,175.30 \\
        \label{tbl:MIDINotes}\\
        \hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{small}
\end{document}
```

This is the current output sample. 
[image]

I've tried to modify `\begin{longtable}{ |C{3cm}|p{3cm}|r|p{3cm}| }` into `\begin{longtable}{ |C{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}| }` (omitting `r`), but it makes all the data is aligned left, including the header.

Comment: Why use fixed width columns? Wouldn't something like `\begin{longtable}{ |c|l|r| }` be sufficient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make two main adjustments:

- encase the material of the final header cell in a `\multicolumn{1}{..}{...}` wrapper to override the default column type; and
- use a `\caption` directive for the `\endhead` material as well, e.g.,

  ```
  \caption{Nomor not MIDI, nama not, dan \textit{center frequency} (Lanjutan)}
  ```

In addition, I'd change the value of the `\LTcapwidth` variable in order to avoid getting an unnecessary-looking line break in the caption. Next, don't hard-code the table "number" by running `\renewcommand\thetable{A}`; instead, please run `\renewcommand\thetable{\Alph{table}}`. I'd also get rid of the `\small` directive as it doesn't seem to be needed; for sure, the cell contents fit just fine without switching to `\small`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, onecolumn, oneside, final]{report}

\usepackage{array}
\setlength\extrarowheight{4pt}

\usepackage{longtable}  

\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\usepackage{musicography}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand\thetable{\Alph{table}} % better than "\renewcommand\thetable{A}"
\setlength\LTcapwidth{\textwidth} % default: 10cm

    \begin{longtable}{ | C{3cm} | L{3cm} | R{3cm} | }

    %% headers and footers:

    \caption{Nomor not MIDI, nama not, dan \textit{center frequency}}
    \label{tbl:MIDINotes}\\
    \hline
    \textbf{Nomor Not MIDI} & 
    \textbf{Nama Not} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{C{3cm}|}{\textbf{\textit{Center frequency}}} \\
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
        
    \multicolumn{3}{C{\dimexpr9cm+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth\relax}}{%
        \textbf{\tablename~\thetable} Nomor not MIDI, nama not, dan
        \textit{center frequency} (Lanjutan)}\\
    \hline
    \textbf{Nomor Not MIDI} & 
    \textbf{Nama Not} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{C{3cm}|}{\textbf{\textit{Center frequency}}} \\
    \hline
    \endhead

    \hline
    \endlastfoot
        

    % body of table:

        127 & G9                        & 12,543.85 \\ \hline
        126 & F$\sharp$9 / G$\flat$9    & 11,839.82 \\ \hline
        125 & F9                        & 11,175.30 \\

    \end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe not a beautiful solution, but it seems to work: Use `\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{\textit{Center frequency}}}` as it allows you to choose alignment.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, onecolumn, oneside, final]{report}
\makeatother

\usepackage{array}
\setlength\extrarowheight{4pt}

\usepackage{tabto}
\newenvironment{tabs}[1]
{\TabPositions{#1}}

\usepackage{longtable}  
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{musicography}

\begin{document}
   
   \begin{small}
      \renewcommand\thetable{A}
      \begin{longtable}{ |C{3cm}|p{3cm}|r|p{3cm}| }
         
         \caption{Nomor not MIDI, nama not, dan \textit{center frequency}}\\
         \hline
         \textbf{Nomor Not MIDI} & \textbf{Nama Not} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{\textit{Center frequency}}} \\
         \endfirsthead
         
         \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{\tablename~\thetable} Nomor not MIDI, nama not, dan \textit{center frequency} (Lanjutan)}\\
         \hline
         \textbf{Nomor Not MIDI} & \textbf{Nama Not} & \textbf{\textit{Center frequency}}
         \endhead
         
         \hline
         127 & G9                        & 12,543.85 \\
         
         \hline
         126 & F$\sharp$9 / G$\flat$9    & 11,839.82 \\
         
         \hline
         125 & F9                        & 11,175.30 \\
         \label{tbl:MIDINotes}\\
         \hline
      \end{longtable}
   \end{small}
\end{document}
```

PS: Are you sure that you need a fourth column or would `\begin{longtable}{ |C{3cm}|p{3cm}|r| }` be sufficient?

Comment: No, I don't need a fourth column for this table. Thank you for the insight!